# networking.service throws "Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway" on debian 12

Tags: linux, nginx, networking, configuration, debian

I am using a proxy server with nginx through which I forward to my application servers.

The app servers have no public IP addresses so I always have to run the traffic through the proxy server.

Since yesterday I have problems with the networking.service

```
× networking.service - Raise network interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-07-25 08:27:34 UTC; 22s ago
       Docs: man:interfaces(5)
    Process: 463 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 703 ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/touch /run/network/restart-hotplug (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 463 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 441ms

Jul 25 08:27:34 gw1-test dhclient[668]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.8 on ens10 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 25 08:27:34 gw1-test dhclient[668]: DHCPACK of 10.0.0.8 from 10.0.0.1
Jul 25 08:27:34 gw1-test ifup[668]: DHCPACK of 10.0.0.8 from 10.0.0.1
Jul 25 08:27:34 gw1-test dhclient[668]: bound to 10.0.0.8 -- renewal in 39911 seconds.
Jul 25 08:27:34 gw1-test ifup[668]: bound to 10.0.0.8 -- renewal in 39911 seconds.
Jul 25 08:27:34 gw1-test ifup[685]: Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
Jul 25 08:27:34 gw1-test ifup[463]: ifup: failed to bring up ens10
Jul 25 08:27:34 gw1-test systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 25 08:27:34 gw1-test systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 25 08:27:34 gw1-test systemd[1]: Failed to start networking.service - Raise network interfaces.
```

In my **/etc/network/interfaces.d** I have following config file:

```
auto ens10
iface ens10 inet dhcp
    post-up ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 # Gateway
    post-up ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.0.0.2 # Route to internet via proxy server
    dns-nameservers 185.12.64.1 185.12.64.2 # dns name server
```

Apps on the server are reachable and I can connect via ssh but I can not ping anything (only local network).

I already changed the debian version to 11 and 10

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have a feeling that this would be better to ask @ [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for that but I already could fix my "problem"

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, but it is not an answer the issue for the networking.service

The reason why I couldn't reach the internet from my app servers were not the networking.service

The networking.service still giving me this error

The problem were my proxy server.

The iptables.service was not running and that was the reason why the traffic from the app serves couldn't get out of the private network.

I checked my iptables.service and started again:

```
user@gw1-proxy:~$ systemctl status iptables.service
● iptables.service - netfilter persistent configuration
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/alternatives/iptables.service; alias)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:netfilter-persistent(8)

user@gw1-proxy:~$ sudo systemctl start iptables

user@gw1-proxy:~$ systemctl status iptables.service
● iptables.service - netfilter persistent configuration
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/alternatives/iptables.service; alias)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2023-07-25 20:16:54 UTC; 11s ago
       Docs: man:netfilter-persistent(8)
    Process: 12595 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 12595 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 13ms
```

And I also had to run this command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

> For the ip you have to add your network interface

I think this is not an answer to this question but it fixed my main problem, so maybe this helps someone also